# Some Widget do not appear when the app started

Tags: flutter

I encounter a bug whenever I build the app for the first time, some widgets are not loaded (it fixes when I do hot reload/restart or change state through setState), and there is no error message whatsoever (after the first build and after hot reload). Here is my code:

`main.dart`

```
    void main() async {
     bootstrap(() async {
      final _repository = ApiRepository();
      return App(
       repository: _repository,
      );
     });
    }
```

`bootstrap.dart`

```
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await runZonedGuarded(() async {
      await BlocOverrides.runZoned(
        () async => runApp(
          await builder(),
        ),
        blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(),
      );
    },(error, stackTrace) => log(error.toString(), stackTrace: stackTrace),
    );
```

`onboarding.dart` -> The error page (I only include the widgets that are not shown)

```
          Column(
            children: [
              PageView.builder(
                    itemCount: slides.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Slider(
                          picture: slides[index].getPicture(),
                          title: slides[index].getTitle(),
                          description: slides[index].getDescription());
                }),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    CustomOutlineButton()
                    const HorizontalSeparator(width: 5),
                    CustomElevatedButton()
                  ],
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Got this message in the first build (the messages do not appear again after hot restart/reload):

```
E/SurfaceSyncer( 6935): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 6935): Expecting binder but got null!
```

The result:

[image]

After hot reload or change State:

[image]